# What other languages, apart from Latin, mix elements from different syntactic constituents? And why mixing?

Tags: syntax, linguistic-typology, list-of-languages, latin, discourse-analysis

Latin has a curious syntactic possibility, which is mixing elements from different constituents, like in the sentence

> Mors et vita **duello** *conflixere* **mirando**

which is translated [by Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duellum#Noun) as

> Death and life *have contended* **in a marvelous combat**

So, in this sentence, the constituent **duello mirando** is split by the verb *conflixere*. Something like that in a literal English translation would be

> Death and life **in a combat** *have contended* **[in a] marvelous**.

If I recall correctly, Ancient Greek doesn't do this, for a comparison. So, about this syntactic feature:

- Is it typologically rare?
- What other languages have it?
- Is it an artificial stylistic option created by baroque-ish authors?
- How probably would it occur in an environment without writing, outside of the literary field (be it prose, written rhetoric and poetry, etc.), or with no conscious intent for style?
- Is the case marking system the main factor that allows this construction to exist?

Comment: This is possible in pretty much any language with the so-called "free word order". Especially in poetry (where this phrase is actually from: [Victimae paschali laudes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victimae_paschali_laudes). Russian: "Жизнь и смерть в этой битве сошлись небывалой". (my ad-hoc translation).

Comment: Ancient Greek does do this as well, though not to the almost fetishising extent that Latin does. Greek tends to prefer keeping at least _some_ level of coherence within constituents. The case you’ve quoted here could easily be found in Greek as well (sandwiching a verb, adverb or participle between an modifier + noun element is one of the more common cases – just think of _ὁ μὲν N_ or _ὁ δὲ N_), but Latin can sometimes mix and match even parallel constituents (<N1 A1> <N2 A2> can become, say, <N1 N2 A1 A2>), which Greek doesn’t normally do.

Comment: Old English poetry does this too

Comment: As a counterexample, Korean has mostly free word order but I don't think it allows these constructions...

Answer (score 5):

In Latin, when part of a constituent "jumps over" an intervening word or phrase, as in your example, this is called *hyperbaton*. It is common in poetry, nor rare in rhetorical prose. It is considered to be a figure of speech, so it is supposed to have stylistic qualities; it is not the normal word order.

In poetry, hyperbaton is also often used *metri causa*. In your example, it is even because of the rhyme:

> Mors et vita duello
> conflixere mirando:
>
> dux vitae mortuus,
> regnat vivus.

Case markings do make it a lot easier to apply.

Considering how frequent it is not only in Latin, still to a large degree a culture centred on spoken language, but also in prehistoric Greek poetry, like Homer, I'd say writing is not at all a requirement.

Depending on your definition, somewhat similar (I suppose) phaenomena can be found in this, dear Reader, very language, in good, old fucking English.

Comment: I don’t really think English counts – sure, you can insert parentheticals and expletives inside many types of constituents, but the fairly doesn’t fixed simply word allow order proper hyberbaton.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Hmm. Hyperbaton aside, English does allow for OP's type of example. Consider, for example, subject-auxiliary inversion, where the subject appears between the first auxiliary and the rest of the matrix VP.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Oh, I agree. I just wanted an excuse to add those English Bits.

Answer (score 0):

Human languages use either morphology or syntax to convey meaning. Morphologically rich languages like Latin can (theoretically) have any word order due to its verb and noun-adjective endings:

The boy loves the little dog
1.Puer amat canem parvum
2.Canem amat parvum puer
3.Parvum puer amat canem
4.Amat puer parvum canem
etc. for a total of 24 possible combinations (The math is: 4 x 3 x 2 x 1)

Latin literature has been "heavily" edited, so what we read today and what/how actual Romans talked is likely "very" different.

Compare the Latin results to English, which becomes gibberish, especially if we treat each word as an independent constituent:

1. *the boy the little loves dog
2. *the dog loves the little boy (wrong b/c the meaning is different from above)
3. *little the boy the loves dog
   etc.